# How to call json file data in my html file ? below is my json file structure

Tags: javascript, html, json

[
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "An ice sculpture",
      "price": 12.50,
   },

{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "A blue mouse",
      "price": 25.50,
   }
]

Comment: please suggest how can I display json data in browser

Comment: USe this link-   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819114/how-to-display-json-data-in-a-div-when-json-data-is-in-array       I got solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Json object :**

```
   var data = [ 
                {  
                  "id": 2, 
                  "name": "An ice sculpture", 
                  "price": 12.50 
                },
                {
                  "id": 3, 
                  "name": "A blue mouse", 
                  "price": 25.50 
                } 
              ];
```

**Iterate every property of the object :**

```
    var htmlContent = '';

    for ( var key in data ) {
        htmlContent += '<div class="container">';
        htmlContent += '<p> Name: ' + data[key].name + '</p>';
        htmlContent += '<p> Price: ' + data[key].ptice + '</p>';
        htmlContent += '</div>';
    }

    $('body').append(htmlContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

$url= "    http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverseformat=json&lat=12.9166&lon=77.6101&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";

```
$json = @file_get_contents($url); $data = json_decode($json);
```

How to receive data from this link.