# how to display JSON objectin javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

please i want to display json data in my javascript. I have been able to get the data from php into JSON encoded form. the connect.php that display encoded JSON is:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

The javascript to display the json encoded is

```
<ul></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('connect.php', function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {

  $('ul').append(val.name);
});
});
});
```

but the data are not being displayed. Please what have i done wrong. Am sorry if this is to trivial.

Comment: look at the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819114/how-to-display-json-data-in-a-div-when-json-data-is-in-array

Comment: why are you appending text to a ul?

Comment: 1) Are you sure your PHP is returning data?  2) What errors do you see in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
$('ul').append(val.name);
```

to:

```
$('ul').append('<li>'+val.name+'</li>');
```

See if helps.