# Javascript methods stop working after writing another method in the same script tag

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I have written a code on codeigniter framework for approve and disapprove leave of employees. The approval and disapproval worked fine before. But after I write another methods in the same script tag for showing the leave details of the employees the approval and disapproval stopped working. 
What can I change in order to make the two buttons work. The two buttons are also inside the modal.

**javascript**

```
    <script> 

    $(function(){

    var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/employeemgt/index.php/";


        $('#pedingLeaveRequest').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var current_leave_id = button.data('id');
            var modal = $(this);

            modal.find('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val(current_leave_id); 
        });     



        //approve button
        $('#approvebtn').click(function(){              
            var id = $('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val();
            $.post(BASE_URL +  'admin/AdminDashboardController/approveLeave', 

                {'id': id}, 
                function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                if(result.error){                       
                    alert('try again');
                }else{
                    alert('Leave has been approved!');
                }
            });              
        });



       //disapprove button
        $('#declinebtn').click(function(){              
            var id = $('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val();
            $.post(BASE_URL +  'admin/AdminDashboardController/disapproveLeave', 

                {'id': id}, 
                function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                if(result.error){                       
                    alert('try again');
                }else{
                    alert('Leave has been disapproved!');
                }
            });              
        });

    });

    //show leave details on modal
    $("#showleave").on('click','button',function(event){
    var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/employeemgt/index.php/";
        var leave_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data:{leave_id:leave_id},
            url: BASE_URL + 'admin/AdminDashboardController/viewRequest',   

        success:function(data){                 
            console.log(data);
            $('#leave_details').html(data);       
            $('#pendingLeaveRequest').modal('show');
       },
       error:function(error){
            alert(error);
        }});
    });


</script>
```

**view:**

```
                    <div id="showleave">
                <h4 class="mb-4">Pending Requests</h4>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($leave as $row) {  
                        if($row->status != "1")
                         {                          
                            echo '
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="media border-bottom border-top py-3">
                                    <img class="mr-3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">'.$row->user_name.'</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-0 mt-0">'.$row->leave_start.' to '.$row->leave_end.'</p>
                                      <p class="mt-0">'.$row->leave_type.'</p>
                                      <button type="button" class="detailButton" href="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-name="'.$row->user_name.'" data-toggle="modal" value="'.$row->id.'">View Request</button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>               
                            </ul>
                            ';
                        }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

**modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="pendingLeaveRequest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Leave Request</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="leave_details" >
            <p> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="current_leave_id" id="current_leave_id" value="" />
            <button type="button" id="declinebtn" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Decline</button>
            <button type="button" id="approvebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Approve</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `var response;` what is this alone? and where is your show leaves button?

Comment: sorry that was a redundant variable. i have updated my code.

Comment: Does show leaves work properly?

Comment: no that is also not working

Comment: `$("#showleave").on('click','button',function(event)` is showleave button?

Comment: no it is the div id which shows the the leave list

Answer (score 1):

As you are replacing the `$('#pendingLeaveRequest #leave_details').html(data);` with new data so the button don't work.. Try to replace it with new id....

```
//show leave details on modal
//$("#showleave").on('click',function(){
$('.detailButton').on('click', function(){
var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/employeemgt/index.php/";
    var leave_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data:{leave_id:leave_id},
        url: BASE_URL + 'admin/AdminDashboardController/viewRequest',   

    success:function(data){                 
        console.log(data);
        $('#leave_details p').html(data);       
        $('#pendingLeaveRequest').modal('show');
   },
   error:function(error){
        alert(error);
    }});
});
```

let me know if it is working..

Comment: is your url correct and check and what about error does it give any error?

Comment: The details are correctly showing in the console and there is no error showing in the console. But no details are on the modal. Yes url is correct

Comment: Now only the leave id is shown in the console and other leave details are not shown

Comment: As your `$("#showleave")` is div so it has lot of value... make it button or pass it the value of leave_id

Comment: earlier the details were shown as,   0
:
{id: "123", user_name: "Harry Potter", user_id: "6", leave_type: "Casual", leave_start: "2018-06-23", …}
length
:
1

Comment: I have edited the code check it now.... and when was above detail shown? if the details were shown then the code is correct.. it is giving data in json format.. you will need to show that json in html in other way...

Comment: Still no details on the modal. But console shows this: [{…}]
0
:
id
:
"124"
leave_end
:
"2018-08-20"
leave_start
:
"2018-08-18"
leave_type
:
"Annual"
status
:
"0"
user_id
:
"6"
user_name
:
"Harry Potter"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: code is working correct than... just learn how to show the json data inside html..... just try it by storing the key=>value in some variable and then push that variable to html by jquery

Comment: I have edited the code run it now... you will have to show data for each row like this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819114/how-to-display-json-data-in-a-div-when-json-data-is-in-array or there are many way to show it, It depends on what you want to show array or single element...

Comment: Still no change after editing the code. but I will check the link you sent.