# Use JSON data to present in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a small JSON like this:

```
   const filmsBase = {
      "films": [
          { "id": 1, "posterId": 111, "title": "The Matrix" },
          { "id": 2, "posterId": 222, "title": "Joker" },
          { "id": 3, "posterId": 333, "title": "The Green Mile" },
      ],
      "posters": [
          { "id": 111, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzQzOTk3OTAtNDQ0Zi00ZTVkLWI0MTEtMDllZjNkYzNjNTc4L2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" },
          { "id": 222, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGVjNWI4ZGUtNzE0MS00YTJmLWE0ZDctN2ZiYTk2YmI3NTYyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" },
          { "id": 333, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzQyNjA5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwOTU2NTY3._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" }
      ]
  }
```

I would like to use it in order to present a movie library in HTML. I need to show `title` and `posters` with corresponding `posterID`.

This is what I've already done:

```
<body>
    <div id="films"></div>
</body>
```

```
filmsBase.films.forEach(function(film){
    titles +=`<h2 class="title">${film.title}</h2>`
})
filmsBase.posters.forEach(function(poster){
    posters +=`<img class="cover" src="${poster.url}">`
})

document.getElementById("films").innerHTML = posters
document.getElementById("films").innerHTML = titles
```

I know that it isn't much, but I have no idea how to continue with the rest of the code. All code needs to be in pure Javascript. Each movie should be in separate div like:

```
<body>
    <div id="films">
        <div class="film">
            <h2 class="title">film.title</h2>
            <img class="poster" src="poster.url">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I will appreciate any feedback and suggestions how to handle this.

Comment: [That is JavaScript, not JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819114/how-to-display-json-data-in-a-div-when-json-data-is-in-array

Comment: Good point, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop over every movie and find the correct poster based on the ID with [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Afterwards you just have to add the new div to the correct DOM node

```
const filmsBase = {
  "films": [
      { "id": 1, "posterId": 111, "title": "The Matrix" },
      { "id": 2, "posterId": 222, "title": "Joker" },
      { "id": 3, "posterId": 333, "title": "The Green Mile" },
  ],
  "posters": [
      { "id": 111, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzQzOTk3OTAtNDQ0Zi00ZTVkLWI0MTEtMDllZjNkYzNjNTc4L2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" },
      { "id": 222, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGVjNWI4ZGUtNzE0MS00YTJmLWE0ZDctN2ZiYTk2YmI3NTYyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" },
      { "id": 333, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzQyNjA5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwOTU2NTY3._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" }
  ]
}
```

.

```
const filmsNode = document.getElementById("films");    

// Loop over films
filmsBase.films.forEach(film => {
  // Find correct poster
  const poster = filmsBase.posters.filter(
    poster => poster.id === film.posterId
  );

  // Create div to put content in
  const newFilm = document.createElement("div");
  newFilm.classList.add("film");

  // Add html to div
  newFilm.innerHTML = `
    <h2 class="title">${film.title}</h2>
    <img class="poster" src="${poster[0].url}" />
  `;

  // Add film to the DOM
  filmsNode.appendChild(newFilm);
});
```

Comment: That is clean and concise solution. Very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
const filmsBase = {
      "films": [
          { "id": 1, "posterId": 111, "title": "The Matrix" },
          { "id": 2, "posterId": 222, "title": "Joker" },
          { "id": 3, "posterId": 333, "title": "The Green Mile" },
      ],
      "posters": [
          { "id": 111, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzQzOTk3OTAtNDQ0Zi00ZTVkLWI0MTEtMDllZjNkYzNjNTc4L2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" },
          { "id": 222, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGVjNWI4ZGUtNzE0MS00YTJmLWE0ZDctN2ZiYTk2YmI3NTYyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" },
          { "id": 333, "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzQyNjA5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwOTU2NTY3._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" }
      ]
  }

const placeholder = document.getElementById("films");
filmsBase.films.forEach(function(film){
  let el = document.createElement("h2");
  el.setAttribute("title", film.title);
  el.innerText = film.title;
  placeholder.appendChild(el);
  let el2 = document.createElement("img");
  var pic = filmsBase.posters.find(function(element) { 
      return element.id === film.posterId; 
      }); 
  el2.setAttribute("src", pic.url);
  placeholder.appendChild(el2);
})
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="films"></div>
</body>
```